# Check geometry type of shapefile with GeoPandas

Tags: geometry, geopandas

Using GeoPandas, how can I check the geometry type of a shapefile (i.e. Point, LineString, Polygon etc).

I can use the following to check the geometry type of each feature but this is unnecessary, I would just like to know if the shapefile is a LineString or not:

```
import geopandas as gpd
df = gpd.read_file('path/to/shapefile')
df.geom_type

0      LineString
1      LineString
2      LineString
3      LineString
4      LineString
             ...
423    LineString
424    LineString
425    LineString

Length: 426, dtype: object
```

Comment: Theoretically and practically, a GeoDataFrame can contain multiple type of geometry ([Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6Ht8.png)). The best option look like using fiona as in BERA's answer.

Comment: @user35594 doesnt my answer work?

Answer (score 2):

Fiona.open seems to be fast (geopandas depend on fiona):

```
import fiona, geopandas, time

#A line shapefile, total size 118 MB
shape = r"/home/bera/Desktop/GIStest/ml_riks.shp"

#Fiona open
start = time.process_time()
c = fiona.open(shape)
if c.schema["geometry"]=='LineString':
    print("Line")
print(time.process_time()-start)
#Line
#0.0016448840000009568

#Geopandas checking geometry type of first feature
start = time.process_time()
df = geopandas.read_file(shape)
if df.iloc[0].geometry.type=='LineString':
    print("Line 2")
print(time.process_time()-start)
#Line 2
#5.306254288999995

#Geopandas checking if all features are linestrings
start = time.process_time()
df = geopandas.read_file(shape)
if df.geom_type.str.contains("LineString").all():
    print("Line 3")
print(time.process_time()-start)
#Line 3
#5.525147246000017
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using GeoPandas and are going to load the shapefile anyway, you can check immediately after reading it by doing `df.geom_type.unique()`. It's good to check in case there are mix of LineString and MultiLineString (or Polygon/MultiPolygon or Point/MultiPoint).